# How to get a rank in Counter-Strike:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

We (as a team) like to play CounterStrike just a few times a year. Last time we tried this in November 2015, we couldn't start any team game. Obviously there is a prerequitite of XP you need to have fulfilled to get a rank which then allows you to play ranked wars.

 What I'm looking for is a definition of these Prerequisites and how to reach them in case it is not self-evident.

As a side note: Before you had to play a number of wars before you were ranked. Afterwards you had a better matchmaking. These ranks we usually lost between just two of our sessions but were quickly refreshed again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an update in CS:GO, which introduced levels in the game, now what these levels are for is pretty much to restrict people from playing MM (MatchMaking) right from the get-go ( pretty much buying the game and playing MM) this way, it would reduce the ammount of "noobs" you would catch in MM, now, to play MM you need to have level 2.

How do you get level 2?

You play, Casual, Arms Race, DeathMatch, even some community servers provide XP, all you have to do is get level 2, this way they can at least "force" the player to know something about the game before playing MM.

When you first start playing you need 10 MM games before a rank is given to you, while you do not have this rank, unless you are in a full lobby (5 people, including you) you will not be able to play with ranks higher than MG1 (Master Guardian 1) the rank insignia is a single AK47.

Remember that if you play with your LEM (Legendary Eagle Master) and DMG (Distinguished Master Guardian) friends, you will have a hard time playing properly (unless you secretly are a csgo pro) since they will be high above your skill cap, which might cause your rank to inflate and make you lose a lot of upcoming games when you play solo, so i suggest, play alone your first 10 games, then play with your friends, **after** you get a rank.

### To answer your question:

1. ***You need level 2 to play MM*** (Level that you get playing Casual and Other games modes).
2. ***You need 10 MM wins before you get a rank***.
3. ***Don't play with your High Rank friends***, you will just drop down when you start playing alone and get de-motivated to continue playing (I know this from personal experience).

Comment: Thanks. I think the level 3 might be the issue. Public playing seems to deliver very few XP and you need a lot to reach lvl. 3. Deathmatch seems to be most effective (according to short research).

Comment: About the XP i am not sure, but yes it takes a while to get level 3, they made it so newcomers actually get some pratice in. No problem, whenever you have a doubt about CS:GO or LoL i will try to reply to the best of my skills, glad i could be of assistance.